# JSTL SQL query Tag DB resulset in JSP

Tags: sql, jsp, tags, resultset, dbconnection

We dont have access to install DB tools like SQL Developer , Oracle live etc ,. in production server. So its very difficult to view the data from the production data base. So I am trying to develop utility web app that has JSP SQL tags which will execute the select query and display the resulset dynamically.
I have below queries .

```
 <sql:query dataSource="${db}" var="rs">  
SELECT * from Students;  
</sql:query>
```

1. Are we able to restrict the sql:query tag that will execute only select queries. Should not execute update or delete queries.

2.If resulset has more rows ,is it possible to have pagination in JSP with SQL JSTL ?

3.How dynamically fetch column names from resulset using JSP SQL tags?

4.Is there any other way to connect DB and Display records in JSP/html.

Comment: Wouldn't you be better allowing access from tools installed on other machines to the production server (with appropriate firewalling / ip lockdowns)

Comment: @Andrew Only way to access the DB is through web application.